# How to write $A, B, C$ and $A^T, B^T, C^T$ explicitly? Which of these matrices are symmetric?

Tags: matrices

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be $4 \times 4$ matrices such that $a_{k,\ell}=2^{k-\ell}$, $b_{k,\ell}=2^{|k-\ell|}$, and $c_{k,\ell}=k^\ell$. How can the matrices $A$, $B$, $C$, $A^T$, $B^T$, and $C^T$ be written explicitly? Which of these matrices are symmetric?

Comment: "Symmetric" means that the element is the same if you swap $k$ and $l$. Which of the matrices do you think behave like that?

Answer (score 1):

Letting $A = [2^{i-j}]_{1 \leq i, j \leq 4}$, $B = [2^{|i-j|}]_{1 \leq i, j \leq 4}$, and $C = [i^j]_{1 \leq i, j \leq 4}$, it is clear that: 
$$A^{T} = [2^{j-i}]_{1 \leq i, j \leq 4}$$

$$B^{T} = [2^{|j-i|}]_{1 \leq i, j \leq 4}$$

$$C^{T} = [j^i]_{1 \leq i, j \leq 4}$$

It is clear that $B$ is symmetric, and that $A$ and $C$ are not symmetric.  For example, $$C = \left(\begin{matrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  2 & 4 & 8 & 16  \\
  3 & 9 & 27 & 81  \\
  4 & 16 & 64 & 256 
 \end{matrix}\right)$$ and: $$C^{T} = \left(\begin{matrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  1 & 4 & 9 & 16  \\
  1 & 8 & 27 & 64  \\
  1 & 16 & 81 & 256 
 \end{matrix}\right).$$

Comment: Why you use i j? Why you write that i<1 and j<4? How do you see that B is symetric?

Comment: @AkaliGreen According to Wikipedia (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29), the entry in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column of a matrix $A$ is sometimes referred to as the $i$,$j$, $(i,j)$, or $(i,j)^{\text{th}}$ entry of the matrix, and most commonly denoted as $a_{i,j}$, or $a_{ij}$. The notation $A = [a_{i,j}]_{1\leq i, j \leq 4}$ is used to indicate that $A$ is a $4 \times 4$ matrix. It is obvious that $B$ is symmetric, because $2^{|i-j|} = 2^{|j-i|}$ for all indices $i$ and $j$.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain me the way you got numbers in matrix

Comment: @AkaliGreen Recall that $C$ is defined as a $4 \times 4$ matrix such that the entry of $C$ in the $i^\text{th}$ row and $j^{\text{th}}$ column is equal to $i^j$. For example, the entry of $C$ in the top left corner of this matrix (i.e., the entry in the first row and first column) is $1^{1}$. Similarly, the entry in the third row and second column is $3^2 = 9$. By definition of the transpose of a matrix, the entry in the $i^{\text{th}}$ row and $j^{\text{th}}$ column of $C^{T}$ is $j^{i}$. For example, the entry in the third row and second column of $C^{T}$ is $2^{3} = 8$.

Comment: What is range of matrix A, B, C